# WP: What callback to be used when page is loaded from app launching

Tags: callback, media-player, windows-phone

Inside MainpPage.xaml.cs, what callback can be used so that I know it is coming from launching the App but not coming from other page? I know that there is Application_Launching in App.xaml.cs. But if I place below code there, exception is thrown somewhere. If I put in Loaded callback, I can't distinguish if it is called from App launching from navigated from other page.

```
            if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing)
            {
                MediaPlayer.Pause();
            }
```

I would like to stop any existing playing music after entering my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you App.xaml:

```
public void TryStopAllMusic()
{
    if (MediaPlayer!=null && MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();  //stop to clear any existing music
    }        
}
```

In the constructor, under InitializeComponent() of your MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    (Application.Current as App).TryStopAllMusic();
}
```

That's all.